# Swift, FIrebase - Can't remove observers by removeAllObservers

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to remove observers for a while but somehow I have never succeeded. I've checked other posts here but I can’ｔ find the reason why.

Here are my codes:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

let timeStamp: Double = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.ref = Database.database().reference()

    guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    self.ref.child("users").child(userId).child("contactList").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let children = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        for child in children {

            guard let dictionary = child.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            guard let timeStamp = dictionary["timeStamp"] as? String else { return }
            guard let timeStampDouble = Double(timeStamp) else { return }

            if timeStampDouble > self.timeStamp {
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(HomeController(), animated: true)
            }

        }

    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch user: ", err)
    }
}

deinit {
    self.ref.child("users").removeAllObservers()
}
```

I would appreciate any advise!

Comment: The call to `observe` should return a handle that you can use to `remove` later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `removeAllObservers` on a node, removes all observers from *that* node only. It doesn't remove observers from child nodes.

So your code:

```
self.ref.child("users").removeAllObservers()
```

This only removes the observers from `users`. It does not remove the observers from `users/$userId/contactList`. To remove the latter, you will have to call `removeAllObservers` on *that* specific node, which means you'll need to track what nodes you have attached observers to.